# MATLAB error: Error Saving Figure: "Object must have an ancestor of type 'figure'"

Tags: matlab, figure

In MATLAB 2012a,
I'm trying to save a figure as a .fig file, and all I get is a window with

Title: Error Saving Figure

Message: Object must have an ancestor of type 'figure'.

I googled this error message, and Google was able to predict my search perfectly, meaning other people have searched the same error message before .. however there is not a single page online that actually discusses this error.

I know that I haven't given much information, and I apologize for this, but I can't imagine what other details to give. 2 minutes ago I saved a different figure generated by the exact same program, in the exact same way, as a .fig file with no problems.

What does this error message mean and how do I fix the problem so that I can save figures in .fig format again ?

Edit: I am trying to save the file from the GUI.

Comment: How do you save the figure? Programmatically? Via the UI?

Comment: Please supply some code so we can help.

Comment: There is no code, I am saving it from the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to relate to how the GUI builds the figures: 
* the parent object is of type 'figure'
* this object has some children of (usually) type 'axis'
* most graphical objects (lines, text, etc) belong to an axis.

It appears to go wrong with figures that have not been built the 'figure;plot(),etc...' way, eg with objects added later to the figure (eg 'legend') or plots that have been made with custom commands ('hist', 'bar3', etc).

My guess is that some GUI object has been added that does not have the figure handle as its 'ancestor'.

Queries about this problem outside StackOverflow seem to involve matlab function 
"getproxyvaluefromhandle". Maybe googling that helps. Someone found help decomposing a figure [here](http://www.gomatlab.de/abspeichern-einer-grafik-t24878.html) (seems to be a mix of Matlab, English and German)

If you have no code can you at least please describe what's in the figure? Otherwise the answers will be as hand-wavy as the question...